# Apt-get update not finding servers when host-only adapter is enabled

Tags: networking, apt, virtualbox

I have this problem where i cannot update because it's just not finding the server. This only happens when i enable host-only adapter.

With only NAT, i can successfully update my server.

I'm just so desperate because literally nothing is working.

```
r0657757@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
0% [Working]
```

IP configuration:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
        address 192.168.1.6
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I can successfully ping to any website.

I've tried uncommenting line 54 of `/etc/gaia.conf` file, changed the `resolv.conf` file to the DNS of Google, and tried disabling anti-virus.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text. Instead, paste the text, select it with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: That is expected behavior for host-only. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly . Your Ubuntu guest VM should NOT be using host-only if you want to keep it updated.

Comment: Then how can i use putty without host-only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host-only as its name implies means that the VM is linked only to the host, not to the Internet. You may enable packet forwarding (aka "Internet sharing") on the host to give Internet access to the VM.

Comment: I tried sharing the internet to the VM's host-only adapter. But still can't update and now i can't even use ssh from putty to my VM.

Comment: Okay the Ip of the adapter changed automatically so had to manually reset it after sharing the connection, i now can use putty but i still cannot update.

Comment: I fixed it, when sharing the wifi with the host-only adapter, i had to manally set the Ip to the same subnet of my host also i had to manually add google's DNS addresses in the ipv4 configuration! Thanks!